# How to make a facebook like plugin on your html website?

Tags: facebook, plugins, web, facebook-like

I am trying to make a plugin in my website just like this one : [image]

I am using this code. It includes the script :

```
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_GB/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

and this :

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="htpp://www.my-site.com/" data-width="600" data-height="30" data-colorscheme="light" data-layout="standard" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-send="true"></div>
```

but nothing shows up. Do I have to use css or a js link included in my page to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing the appId. Make sure to create a Facebook application and connect it with your plugin.
[image: plugin code]